# wrap() in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new in jquery and trying to find out way that how to use `wrap()` in my menues of website following in my code

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
</ul>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.menu li a').text().wrap('<span></span>');
```

But its not working :(

I want to look my `HTML` code like following code i just want to add `<span>` tag into `<a>` tag

**CODE**

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#"><span>Who We Are</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><span>Our Work</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Please help me friends THANKS in advance ...:)

Comment: Where did you get `.test()` from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take `wrapInner`, like so:

`$('li a').wrapInner('<span/>');​`

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ucj5v/2/

Why the `.test()`?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you do `not` have `test()` method that you can call with the elements returned by selector and second you need [**wrapInner()**](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) instead of `wrap`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Rz2bZ/1/)**

Change

```
$('.menu li a').test().wrap('<span></span>');
```

To

```
$('ul li a').wrapInner('<span></span>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap would put the span around the a.

You can do this :

```
$('.menu li a').each(function(){
     $(this).html('<span>'+$(this).html()+'</span>');
});
```

[Demonstration (open the console to see the final HTML)](http://jsfiddle.net/PxM5r/)

I suppose you meant `text` and not `test`. If so be aware that `text` doesn't return the text node but just a string, so you can't use it as a jQuery element and you can't call `wrap` on it.

Comment: thanks for help but your code will add `<span>` around the `<a>` tag and i want to add `<span>` into `<a>`....

Comment: @user1849368 Look at the generated code (open the console) : the span is inside the `a` element.